# IE treating jQuery mousedown/mouseup as a double click

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

IE9 is making the mouseup command in my jQuery to behave strangely. The mousedown command fires but the mouseup command does not. Instead the user has to double click the button to fire the mouseup command. I could just have a click but it would remove the button effect which I like so would prefer to keep it.

jQuery;

```
$('#voteButton').live('mousedown', function(){

   $(this).replaceWith('<img src="files/images/voting_button_active.png" width="100" height="100" alt="Vote Button" id="voteButton">');


   }).live('mouseup', function(){
   $(this).replaceWith('<img src="files/images/voting_button.png" width="100" height="100" alt="Vote Button" id="voteButton">');
    $('#votePanel').load('template/votePanel.php');




});
```

Note: The replaceWith on the mouseup command is just there in case the mouseup is cancelled

Comment: Is this a similar scenario? http://jsfiddle.net/MLVvT/

Comment: Yes exactly the same thing going one

Comment: Edited response after retesting in jsfiddle. The prevent default approach should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `html` of the element instead of replacing the entire element seems to work a little better:

```
$('#voteButton').live('mousedown', function(){
    $(this).html('<img src="files/images/voting_button_active.png" width="100" height="100" alt="Vote Button" id="voteButton">');
}).live('mouseup', function(){
    $(this).html('<img src="files/images/voting_button.png" width="100" height="100" alt="Vote Button" id="voteButton">');
    $('#votePanel').load('template/votePanel.php');
});
```

Obviously, this will require changes to your markup--basically you'd be using a container element and swapping out the inner contents.

Comment: Not ideal but if it has to be done, it has to be done. Maybe some others will have simpler solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The jsfiddle that Andrew provided works for me in IE9. Have you checked to see if you are accidentally moving the cursor outside of the bounds of the re-sized div when the first image is provided? The mouse-up event will only fire if you're still in the div. You may want to attach to the mouseout event and set a status on the mousedown so that if you mouse out of the div while mousedown is active it treats the mouseout as a mouseup.

Edit: Add prevent default to your mousedown event and the subsequent mouseup should fire appropriately in IE9.

```
$(function () {
    $("#vote").live("mousedown", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).replaceWith("<img src='http://www.placekitten.com/100/100' id='vote' />");        
    }).live("mouseup", function () {
        $(this).replaceWith("<img src='http://www.placekitten.com/200/200' id='vote' />");
    });
});​
```

Comment: The prevent default removes the button effect in IE but I can live with that. IE 10 is coming soon anyway which should fix it.